# Pip install commands error ConnectTimeoutError

Tags: python, django, proxy, pip

I am trying to install Django 1.8.11 on my Windows 10 PC, but i am getting this error when run `pip install django==1.8.11`:

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CE97C60D68>, 'Connection to xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/

(`xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx` Is an address that I use as proxy some times)

I have Python version: 3.5.4

and pip version: 9.0.1

I have checked proxy settings with `netsh winhttp show proxy`

> Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
>
> Direct access (no proxy server).

I am not behind any corporate proxy
My system proxy settings are

> Automatically detect settings -> ON

> Use setup script -> OFF

> Use a proxy server -> OFF

Also tried `ping pypi.python.org`

> Ping statistics for 151.101.4.223:
> Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
> Minimum = 92ms, Maximum = 102ms, Average = 95ms

So, I have access to the internet

Also i removed temp files, tried `python -m pip --proxy="" install django==1.8.11`, searched the registry for data or value `xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx`, same result...

If anyone knows where is that `xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx` configured so I can remove it, don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the current environment variables, try to find any proxy setting:

```
set | find "proxy"
```

If anything found — unset the variables.

List settings from the config file:

```
pip config list | find "proxy"
```

If anything found — unset the variable using `pip config unset` or `pip config edit`. See the docs for `pip config` at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/

Comment: Thanks i tried: `set | find "proxy"` and finally got `https_proxy=https://xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx`, but when I use `pip config unset "proxy"` i get `ERROR: unknown command "config"`

Comment: @sgClaudia98 `set` shows environment variables, not `pip` settings. To unset it just `set https_proxy=`. See https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: thanks a lot MARKED as CORRECT, your response helped find were it was so, what i did was `set https_proxy=` then tried again `set | find "proxy"` and got blank result. I know is not permanent solution but now I know that is in a `variable` I will get to remove it later. Again thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the latest version `pip install Django`

https://pypi.org/project/Django/

Comment: same error, is not the version, is some proxy config I don't know were it is